# Google Apps Script - remove spaces using .replace method does not work for me

Tags: string, google-apps-script

I am using Google Apps Script to create apps.
I encounter issue when I try to remove whitespaces from my spreadsheet value.
I have referred alot of posts & comments in stackoverflow and other forum too. They are all talking about using **.replace** method.
However, **.replace** method does not work for me.

```
var ItemArray = <<getValue from google spreadsheet>>
var tValue = ItemArray[0][2].toString();

for (var row = 0; row<ItemArray.length; row++)
{
   var TrimmedStrA = ItemArray[row][2].toString().replace(' ', '');
   var TrimmedStrB = tValue.replace(' ', '');

   if (TrimmedStrA == TrimmedStrB)
   {
      <<other code>>

   } //end if
} //end of loop
```

Comment: This is not trimming. Trim is meant to remove whitespaces from the sides up to the nearest non-whitespace character; not from the entire string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A simple RegExp object should be used in the `replace()` method.  `\s` is a simple solution to find whitespace. The 'g' provides a global match for instances of whitespace:

```
tValue.replace(/\s/g, "")
```

This will get you pretty close without knowing what your data looks like.

[.replace() documentation here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score 2):

You may use split function followed by join. It's very simple to use.

```
yourString = yourString.split(" ").join("")
```

It'll remove all spaces no matter where they are located in the stirng.