# Google Apps Script - remove spaces using .replace method

Tags: google-docs

I'm trying to replace multiple whitespaces with single ones in a Google Doc with a script. But unfortunately the provided solution [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16547060/google-apps-script-remove-spaces-using-replace-method-does-not-work-for-me) isn't working for me. As you can see, I tried several alternatives but can not figure out how to do it right. Any ideas?

```js
function searchAndReplace() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()
      .getBody();
  body.replaceText(/\s{2,}/,' ');
  body.replaceText(/\s/g, " ") ;
  body.replaceText("/\s/"," ");
  body.replaceText('/\s{2,}/',' ');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```js
function searchAndReplace() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  body.editAsText().replaceText('\\s*', ' ');
}
```

**UPDATE**

One option is:

```js
function getCorrections() {
  var _getCorrections = 0,
      text = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getText(),
      regexp = /\s+/g,
      matchesCorrections = text.match(regexp);

  if (matchesCorrections) {
    _getCorrections = matchesCorrections.reduce(function(previousValue,
                                                         currentValue) {
      return previousValue + currentValue.length - 1;
    }, 0);
  }

  return _getCorrections;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works! Would you mind adding a report showing number of corrections?

Comment: how do I display the number of corrections like in a toast message? and how do I add this functionality in the menu bar? Feel free to not answer it, I will grant the bounty anyways. It takes 24 hours.

Comment: @Thoran: See [Dialogs and Sidebars in Google Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs) and [Custom Menus in Google Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus).